# how to pull out text from a div class using selenium headless

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to pull out the "0%" from the following div tag:

```
<div class="sem-report-header-td-diff ">0%</div>
```

my current code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='mypath/chrome.exe',
                      chrome_options=options)

url = 'https://www.semrush.com/info/burton.com'
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
change_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath='//div[@class="sem-report-header-td-diff "]')
```

not sure what I'm doing wrong. This works with href tags, but its not working for this.

Comment: Where the text extracting line?

Comment: the last line is what I've been using to pull out the elements. `driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath=`

Comment: *Elements*, but not *text*. How did you try to extract text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the HTML you have shared to extract the text **0%** you need to use the method `get_attribute("innerHTML")` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `css_selector`:

  ```
  myText = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.sem-report-header-td-diff").get_attribute("innerHTML")
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  myText = driver.find_element_by_xpath("div[@class='sem-report-header-td-diff']").get_attribute("innerHTML")
  ```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks @DebanjanB!

Comment: actually - for some reason, its pulling a different value from the page, but I'm not sure where. The location for this one  (webs.com) is here: [semRush](https://www.semrush.com/info/webs.com?is_new=1) and I'm trying to pull the bubble next to Organic Search showing 0%. This code ends up grabbing -7% for some reason.

Comment: @MattW. I am getting blocked by a username/password challenge? Have you got a demo credentials?

Comment: kind of strange. No I'm not/Don't have one

Comment: Can you copy the HTML and paste it within the question area?

Comment: Not sure how. If you follow the link in my earlier comment and right click and inspect source for that webpage on the bubble next to Organic Search, that will lead you there. I actually even copied the Xpath from source, and it gave me the wrong #s too.

Comment: the xpath interestingly enough showed as this: `//*[@id="organicSummary"]/div[2]/div[2]/div`, but it comes out to the same answer as what you're providing

Answer (score 0):

First of all, not "elements", it is "element". and, second point is, you didn't get ttext. you just called element.

so, here is the code:

> element_text =
>   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='sem-report-header-td-diff']").text

Comment: your code doesn't work. it returns an empty list, to which you can't call a text method.

Comment: i updated xpath. can you check it now again?

Comment: `no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='sem-report-header-td-diff ']"}`

Comment: Are you sure your xpath/element is correct. i just copied from element that you presented in your question.

Comment: the other question was able to accurately get it. so yes.